# OpenGL framebuffer affected by size of window

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I am using OpenGL with GLSL shaders to do some image processing. I'm basically using framebuffers with an orthographic projection to render my image multiple times (each with different settings for the fragment shader).

I then have 2 framebuffers with textures attached to them that I render back and forth between (eg. tex1 is attached to fb1, tex2 is attached to fb2. first pass renders the input texture into fb1, second pass renders tex1 into fb2, 3rd pass renders tex2 into fb1... back and forth) until the final pass renders from whatever texture into an output framebuffer.

All of this is done using orthographic projections so none of the image should be missing. This all works fine until the window is resized. If I decrease the height of the window by half the image ends up only being drawn in the top half of the window that's left (this is for one pass, 2 passes and it will end up only in the top 1/4 of the window). Can anyone understand why this is happening?

The second pic is after resizing the window to 3/4 its original height

http://i567.photobucket.com/albums/ss112/davidc538/rtip1.png

http://i567.photobucket.com/albums/ss112/davidc538/rtip2.png

Comment: This is a lot of information to process, a snapshot would help understanding.

Comment: I've added links, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not updating your texture dimensions when the resize occurs.
i.e. your window has resized, but you're still blitting to its initial dimensions.

- Pass 1 writes tex1 (which is attached to fb1)
- Pass 2 writes tex1 (which is attached to fb1) to tex2 (fb2)
- Pass 3 writes tex2 back to tex1
- Pass 3 writes tex1 back to tex2

That would mean you are shrinking/enlarging your image on every pass.

You can avoid this by updating your fbo's during the resize (I'd advise rounding to the nearest larger power-of-two), or by leaving the fbo's at a fixed size and always rendering to the full window (although your image would be blurry when rendered to a large window).

Comment: Shouldn't my FBO's be able to operate entirely independently of the window size though? I'd like to be able to show the unprocessed webcam input on one side of the window and the processed input on the other but doubling the width of the window enlarges the image on every pass. Thanks for the input though I really just can't understand why the size of the window is interfering with my ability to process an image this way.

Comment: The resolution of an FBO has nothing to do with how it appears when you draw it to the screen. You can blit an FBO to an arbitrary rectangle, or texture map it to triangles that cover any portion of the screen you want. It is your responsibility to make sure that when the window is resized, whatever technique you are using to show the contents of the FBO respects the new window dimensions. But I suspect in your vague description, what you forgot was that `glViewport (...)` is a global state you are probably setting it when you resize your window and neglecting to re-set it when binding an FBO.

Comment: I actually just discovered GLUT was doing that for me because I didn't specify a reshapefunc, but yes this is totally the case. Thanks!